# Regex replace within match

Tags: regex, notepad++

In Notepad++ RegEx, I want to search for all strings starting with a tilde and terminating with \n, and within each match replace all spaces with non-breaking spaces.

That is, I want to find all instances of `\~.*^`, and within the resulting `$0`, replace all `[Space]s` with `[Non-breaking Space]`.

Is this possible?

Comment: what do you mean by non breaking space?

Comment: @karthikmanchala blanks and tabstops I assume

Comment: yes it's possible but it would help if you gave an example line that you want to run the regex on (and expected output)

Comment: @karthikmanchala &nbsp;?

Comment: Not sure if notepad++ regex engine is powerful enough for this sort of thing but here is a php solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18581227/regex-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-single-character-within-specific-tokens

Comment: A non-breaking space character looks like an ordinary space, but is treated by text editors as a non-delimiter. It's Unicode  U+00A0, HTML &nbsp; and Alt+255

Comment: Example: 'God is dead' ~ Frederich Nietzsche. The space before the ~ would remain a normal space. The spaces after it and before the N would become non-breaking spaces. Thus "~ Frederich Nietzsche" would become a single "word", from the users point of view.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following to match:

```
(?:~|\G(?<!^))\S*\K\s
```

Or try:

```
(?:~|\G(?!^))\S*\K[ ]
```

And replace with non breaking space

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/bW4hA5/5)

[Credits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18581227/regex-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-single-character-within-specific-tokens)

Comment: Sorry, in N++ that just replaces all spaces. Maybe a weakness in N++'s implementation of regex. I'll try to reverse engineer from the demo.

Comment: Good idea! Maybe not working for @Kapitano because of `\s` at the end. Try `(?:~|\G(?!^))\S*\K[ ]`

Comment: @Jonny5 hmm.. maybe.. I tried it with `\s` in N++ and it works.. in anycase.. updated with your suggestion too.. :)

Answer (score 0):

With fixed-width pattern lookbehind regex engines (e.g., Perl):

```
s/(~.*?) {2,}/\1 /g
```

with variable-width pattern lookbehind regex engines:

```
s/(?<=\~.*) {2,}/  /g
```

or with Vim:

```
s/\(\~.*\)@<= \{2,}/  /g
```

I'm not sure about Notepad++. Hopefully you can work it out based on the above.